# Qt cannot linking with g++

Tags: c++, qt

Hi everyone this is the first time I ask question here

I am trying to compile simple Qt c++ code with g++ but every time it gives me:

```
C:\Users\ctw\AppData\Local\Temp\ccrszXqF.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x32): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN12QApplicationC1ERiPPci'
C:\Users\ctw\AppData\Local\Temp\ccrszXqF.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x6e): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN11QPushButtonC1ERK7QStringP7QWidget'
C:\Users\ctw\AppData\Local\Temp\ccrszXqF.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xa6): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN7QWidget4showEv'
C:\Users\ctw\AppData\Local\Temp\ccrszXqF.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xad): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN12QApplication4execEv'
C:\Users\ctw\AppData\Local\Temp\ccrszXqF.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xbb): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN12QApplicationD1Ev'
C:\Users\ctw\AppData\Local\Temp\ccrszXqF.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xe9): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN12QApplicationD1Ev'
C:\Users\ctw\AppData\Local\Temp\ccrszXqF.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN7QStringC1EPKc[__ZN7QStringC1EPKc]+0x2c): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN7QString16fromAscii_helperEPKci'
C:\Users\ctw\AppData\Local\Temp\ccrszXqF.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN7QWidget6resizeEii[__ZN7QWidget6resizeEii]+0x2f): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN7QWidget6resizeERK5QSize'
C:\Users\ctw\AppData\Local\Temp\ccrszXqF.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN15QTypedArrayDataItE10deallocateEP10QArrayData[__ZN15QTypedArrayDataItE10deallocateEP10QArrayData]+0x1d): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN10QArrayData10deallocateEPS_jj'
```

The compile command is:

```
g++ -o main.exe  main.cpp C:\Qt_\5.0.2\msvc2010\lib\Qt5Core.lib C:\Qt_\5.0.2\msvc2010\lib\Qt5Core.lib
```

The code I tried to compiling is:

```
#include <QtWidgets/qapplication.h>
#include <QtWidgets/qpushbutton>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     QApplication app(argc, argv);
     QPushButton *hello = new QPushButton("This is a simple button");
     hello->resize(100, 30);
     hello->show();
     return app.exec();
}
```

The version of g++ is:

```
g++ (GCC) 5.3.0
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

I am using Qt 5.0.2 32bit. I am a beginner of C++ and I tried to solve with this problem for about a week. Can anyone tell me what should I do to compile successfully?

Comment: What definitely won't work is to use libs compiled with the Microsoft compiler with gcc. msvc2010 refers to the 2010 version of the Microsoft visual c compiler. Since the libs use a C++ interface, you need to use the same compiler.

Comment: @PaulR. Thanks for answering me. I will compile it with that compiler.

Comment: Try with `g++ -o main.exe  main.cpp -LC:\Qt_\5.0.2\msvc2010\lib\Qt5Core.lib -LC:\Qt_\5.0.2\msvc2010\lib\Qt5Core.lib`

Comment: @OnurTuna `-L` specifies a directory, not a library file.

Comment: @aschepler ok give the path of the libraries

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a reason not to upgrade your Qt instalatioon, please do so, 5.0.2 is really old and buggy, we are in the version 5.8 now.
Now, to your problem:

You are trying to compile an application using different compilers, see, your Qt was compiled with Visual Studio (and you can tell this by the path of the library that you are trying to link manually).

The other thing, Qt files usually pass to a pre-processing state before being send to the compiler, I know that your particular code doesn't have this error *yet*, but as soon as you increase the code size you will hit that, so use a project manager that has knowledge of Qt internals, like qmake, qbs or CMake (I prefer the later), this will choose the right Qt kit and run moc before compilling your application.

The last thing, if you use the visual studio version of Qt, you need to compile it with the cl compiler, not with Gcc. if you download the Qt Installer, it will ask if you have the mingw version (that comes with g++) or the visual studio version.

Answer (score 0):

For your problem, you need to use the "MinGW" version of the Qt libs. Actually you can only compile your project with Visual Studio 2010 compiler.

You can find the right libs here : [Qt 5.0.2 Archive](https://download.qt.io/archive/qt/5.0/5.0.2/)

Also you'll need MinGW 4.7.